# Auto click filter link once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a web template and I do not really know how to change the functionality, so I just want to implement what i assumed was a quick fix to a page. The page (www.syncpad.us/forms.html) has quite a lot of thumbnails and a filtering system.

My problem is that when I first load the page, the thumbs kind of stack on top of each other after the first 3 rows. If I click the All filter, they behave as they should & have their own space.

All I wanted to do was have the All filter link auto clicked once after load to sort thumbs correctly.

I have tried some obvious solutions, but haven't gotten far.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#allfilter').click(); 
});</script>
```

as well as

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#allfilter')[0].click(function(){
 }); 
});<script>
```

and lots of variations of these but can't get it to do what I need it to do.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If all filter has got some method to click on it, you should only call this method not on click but just myMethod()

Comment: We need to see what the `all` filter does in code to help you